# Nested for each loop 10 by 10 gives over 1000 loops

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm seriously dumbfound by this issue, I have a nested for-next loop that gives over a thousand loops I know this from seeing this code:

```
'find row ranges for department 1-10
    For i = 1 To 10 Step 1
        Dim tempRange As Range
        Set tempRange = GetRowRange(importsheet, DepColumn, i)
        'and iterate through the columns to insert them
        ' find row ranges for section
        If Not (importsheet.UsedRange.Find("afdeling_" & i) Is Nothing) Then
            Dim SecColumn
            Dim secRange As Range
            SecColumn = importsheet.UsedRange.Find("afdeling_" & i).column
            Set bCell = tempRange.Columns(SecColumn)
            tempRange.Sort Key1:=bCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
            For ix = 1 To 10 Step 1
                'check for a valid section column
                Set secRange = GetRowRange(tempRange, SecColumn, ix)
                totalposts = totalposts + IterateColumns(secRange, spgsheet, importsheet, debugsheet, year, month, week, Hospital, i, ix, varType, False)
                Progress
            Next ix
        Else
        totalposts = totalposts + IterateColumns(tempRange, spgsheet, importsheet, debugsheet, year, month, week, Hospital, i, 0, varType, False)
        End If
        Progress
    Next i
```

My progress function looks like this:

```
Function Progress()
iProgress = iProgress + 1
Application.StatusBar = Format(iProgress, "0%") & " Completed"
End Function
```

but the progressbar will often show up to 3300%.

How's that even possible?

Comment: 1 = 100% , so 33 = 3300%

Comment: You would be better served asking this on stackoverflow

Comment: **There is no possible way this code is ran 1,000 times.**  You either didn't post all the code or your debugging methods are flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not showing all of the code. For example, I assume thst `iProgress` is globally defined but we can't see that here.

Also, why are you doing `DIM` statements inside a loop? You should only do them once and also you should be setting object variables to `nothing` once you've finished with them. Failure to do that is likely to result in some nasty memory issues along the way.

To answer the specific question. You've set `iProgress` to be a counter not a %.

To get the %, you need to know how many items you will be iterating over before starting the progress bar. You then need the current item counter and the total. `CurrentCount/TotalItemCount` gives you the progress.